# is this expression awkward?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> To look at the picture by dividing it into the part A and the Part B, You would understand the chart.

is this expression awkward?
I can't search "To look at * by dividing" at google.
if it's the right sentence, Why is not it searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect English, and quite difficult to understand what you mean.

The second part "you would understand the chart" is a conditional expression, and correct grammar.  The conditional expression should have an "if" clause or similar.

> If you wore a coat, you would be warm.
>
> If you knew French, you would understand the French songs.

You can't use a "to" infinitive.

So what you most likely mean is:

> If you looked at the picture by dividing it into <s>the</s> part A and part B, you would understand the chart.

That is grammatically correct English, but "dividing" is not a method for "looking", so "look by dividing..." is odd.  You could "look and divide"

> If you looked at the picture and divided it into part A and part B, you would understand the chart.

But do you need to say "look"?  Isn't it obvious that you need to look at something? I would just cut that part completely. I would also not use past tense "would" as we don't need a hypothetical situation.

> If you divide the picture into parts A and B, you will understand the chart.

Comment: Please explain "dividing" is not a method for "looking"  in more detail. It is difficult to understand the concept because it is Korean.

Comment: @sechuljang *to look at* essentially means *to see* (with ones eyes). I think you might be looking for an expression like *to see X **as*** (or *to visualize X*, *to imagine X*, *to think of X as*, etc.). "If you **imagine** the picture being divided into parts A & B, you will understand the chart."

Answer (score 0):

If by expression, you are referring to only **"to look at,"** then there's nothing wrong with that. However, **"to look at by dividing"** is certainly wrong.

How about this:

> By **looking at the picture and dividing it** into Part A and Part B, you would be able to understand the chart.